# InvalidCastException on attemp to CreateInstance() of Type from external Assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, assemblies

I have a project that stores data of "custom" types and each of these types is represented as a class. I am able to collect these types from assembly and create instances of these when I need to in run time:

```
var type = typeof(IDataPointListableCore);
            var availableTypes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                                          .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
                                          .Where(w => w.IsAbstract == false)
                                          .Where(x => type.IsAssignableFrom(x));
...
IDataPointListableCore c = (IDataPointListableCore)Activator.CreateInstance(item, "");
```

It worked fine but an obvious disadvantage of this approach is that if I want to add a new type I have to rebuild and deploy the application. So I decided to externalize these classes into .ddl assemblies that I would be loading from a folder on application start.

A sample type would look like this:

```
namespace DataPoints
{
    public class DataPointRAG : IDataPoint<string>
    {
        private enum AcceptedValues { none, red, amber, green };
        public string ParsedValue { get; private set; } = null;
        public string Name { get; } = "nRAG";
        public string Description { get; } = "One of the four RAG indicators: None, Red, Amber, Green";
        public string Value { get; private set; }

        public DataPointRAG(string _v)
        {
            Value = _v;
        }

        public Type GetExpectedValueType()
        {
            return typeof(string);
        }

        public string GetParsedValue()
        {
            return ParsedValue;
        }

        public ValidationResult Validate()
        {
            if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(AcceptedValues), Value.ToLower()))
            {
                ParsedValue = Value.ToLower();
                return new ValidationResult(true, "OK");
            }
            return new ValidationResult(false,
                                        string.Format("Given value ({0}) does not correspond to any of the accepted values {1} for this data point type",
                                                      Value,
                                                      Enum.GetValues(typeof(AcceptedValues)).ToString()));
        }
    }
}
```

And it implements two interfaces (I reference a project with these):

```
namespace DataPoints
{
    public interface IDataPointListable
    {
        string Name { get; }
        string Description { get; }
        string ParsedValue { get; }
        string Value { get; }
        ValidationResult Validate();
    }
}

namespace DataPoints
{
    public interface IDataPoint<T> : IDataPointListable
    {
        System.Type GetExpectedValueType();
        T GetParsedValue();
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I load the assembly and try to instantiate this class, it throws an `InvalidCastException: can't cast DataPoints.DataPointRAG to IDataPointListable`

```
public static List<Assembly> Asses = new List<Assembly>();
...
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var _loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory()
                .AddConsole(LogLevel.Debug)
                .AddDebug();

            var _logger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger("Startup");

            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(DATAPOINTSFOLDER, "*.dll");
            foreach (string f in files)
            {
                Assembly DataPointsAssembly = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(f);
                Asses.Add(DataPointsAssembly);
            }

            foreach (Type _assType in Asses.SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes()))
            {
                _logger.LogDebug("Found {0} in {1}", _assType, _assType.FullName);
            }

            foreach (Type _assType in Asses.SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes()).Where(x=>typeof(IDataPointListable).IsAssignableFrom(x)))
            {
                _logger.LogDebug("Found matching assemblies");
                var point = (IDataPointListable)Activator.CreateInstance(_assType, "");
                _logger.LogDebug("{0} successfully initiated", point.Name);
            }

            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }
```

It does not recognize any of the found types as Assignable to IDataPointListable:

```
log:
[40m[37mdbug[39m[22m[49m: Startup[0]
      Found DataPoints.DataPointRAG in DataPoints.DataPointRAG
[40m[37mdbug[39m[22m[49m: Startup[0]
      Found DataPoints.ValidationResult in DataPoints.ValidationResult
[40m[37mdbug[39m[22m[49m: Startup[0]
      Found DataPoints.IDataPoint`1[T] in DataPoints.IDataPoint`1
[40m[37mdbug[39m[22m[49m: Startup[0]
      Found DataPoints.IDataPointListable in DataPoints.IDataPointListable
[40m[37mdbug[39m[22m[49m: Startup[0]
      Found DataPoints.DataPointRAG+AcceptedValues in DataPoints.DataPointRAG+AcceptedValues
```

but if I try something like this (just to load the type based on the class name since I know it implements the proper interface) - I will get the InvalidCastException:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(DATAPOINTSFOLDER, "*.dll");
            foreach (string f in files)
            {
                Assembly DataPointsAssembly = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(f);

                foreach(Type _t in DataPointsAssembly.GetTypes()){
                    _logger.LogDebug("Type {0} in Assembly {1}", _t, DataPointsAssembly.FullName);
                    if (_t.ToString() == "DataPoints.DataPointRAG"){
                        var x = (IDataPointListable)Activator.CreateInstance(_t, "");
                        _logger.LogDebug("Activated class of type {0}", x.GetType());
                    }
                }
```

if I don't cast to IDataPointListable then it will generate an instance of the DataPointRAG and the public class fields will be in there but it will be as if the class implemented no interfaces at all.

Is there something I am missing from how things work when loaded from external assembly?

The structure of my project is:

- Core->References DataPointTemplate project (DataPoints namespace)
- DataPointTemplate project provides the two interfaces and
- ValidationMessage class Data PointRAG project->References DatapointTemplate project, but same namespace

Comment: How do you load the assembly, `Assembly.Load()`, `LoadFrom()` or `LoadFile()`? And to understand the situation better, you have one assembly trying to load the class, one library containing the `DataPointRAG` class, and one library containing the interface, referenced by the other two assemblies?

Comment: I use `AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(f)`, I am trying to load a lib containing DataPointRAG class, since it implements interfaces, they are as well exposed. I updated my questions to arrange for more details, my initial explanation wasn't complete.